# using send_file in deferred sinatra request

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to return a file during an async sinatra request, something like this:

```
aget "/test" do
  if(File.exists?("test.tar"))
    send_file("test.tar", :filename => "test.tar", :type => "application/octet-stream")
    return
  end

  EM.defer(proc{
      # create test.tar
    },
    proc{ |r|
      send_file("test.tar", :filename => "test.tar", :type => "application/octet-stream")
    })
```

However it seems that when I do that, I get an error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
file: file.rb
location: call
line: 29
```

BACKTRACE:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/file.rb in call
    def call(env)
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/async_sinatra-1.0.0/lib/sinatra/async.rb in block in body
    response.body = Array(async_handle_exception {response.body.call})
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/async_sinatra-1.0.0/lib/sinatra/async.rb in async_handle_exception
    yield
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/async_sinatra-1.0.0/lib/sinatra/async.rb in body
    response.body = Array(async_handle_exception {response.body.call})
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb in invoke
    body(res.pop)
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/async_sinatra-1.0.0/lib/sinatra/async.rb in block in async_catch_execute
    invoke { halt h }
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/async_sinatra-1.0.0/lib/sinatra/async.rb in async_handle_exception
    yield
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/async_sinatra-1.0.0/lib/sinatra/async.rb in async_catch_execute
    async_handle_exception do
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/async_sinatra-1.0.0/lib/sinatra/async.rb in block in async_schedule
    native_async_schedule { async_catch_execute(&b) }
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb in call
    end.each { |j| j.call }
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb in block in run_deferred_callbacks
    end.each { |j| j.call }
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb in each
    @next_tick_mutex.synchronize do
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb in run_deferred_callbacks
    @next_tick_mutex.synchronize do
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb in run_machine
    run_machine
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb in run
    run_machine
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb in start
    EventMachine.run(&starter)
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb in start
    @backend.start
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb in run
    server.start
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb in run!
    handler.run self, :Host => bind, :Port => port do |server|
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/main.rb in block in <module:Sinatra>
    at_exit { Application.run! if $!.nil? && Application.run? }


end
```

Comment: why not have the `EM` block within the `if` statement and remove the first call to `send_file`?

Comment: what is the code located on line 29

Comment: also i am sure that its a typo but you have aget instead of get in first line of your code

Answer (score 0):

The error  you are receiving is cause you are using a function that requires 1 argument and you haven't supplied any.  If you can show us the code around line 29 I or somebody can point it out for you.